# MPAndroidchart-CombinedChart don't draw start zero?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use `mpandroidchart-combinedchart` for Stock chart.

[image]
the bottom chart did not start from 0,who can help me? 
I try chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0); but it didn't work.

Comment: I find it the chart draw from 0,it is the 0 line and border have a little space.but I don't know why

Comment: @ Raymond Arteaga yes,I set don't show the axis,I set the chart border for project ui.I mean the chart didn't aligned with the underlying line

Comment: have you tried with setViewPortOffsets() ?

Comment: Try with chart.getAxisLeft().setSpaceBottom(0f)

Comment: @Raymond Arteaga,yes,it works,chart.getAxisLeft().setSpaceBottom(0f),thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with chart.getAxisLeft().setSpaceBottom(0f)